# Last results submitted in mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, resultset, relational, relational-database

How would i get the last 20 results submitted in a mysql db row.

I need the 20 most recent user submitted results.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an auto_increment primary key, its as simple as:

```
SELECT * FROM that_table
ORDER BY auto_increment_primary_key DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

Comment: for some reason i am only getting one result back when i have 2 results in the database.

Comment: here is the code "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY table_id DESC LIMIT 0, 20"

Comment: that's impossible! you have not specified a `where` clause in the query you just posted so you *should* see upto 20 records

Comment: No your right. It was infact a quirk in codeigniter that prevented more than one result showing up.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have timestamp or autoincrement field on that table then you can't.

Otherwise : `select * from table order by id desc limit 0,20`

Answer (score 0):

See the Query below, there is an function available in mysql syntax below

`SELECT  FROM  ORDER BY  DESC LIMIT 0,20`